# How to create keycloak with operator and external database

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I follow [this](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_external_database) but it is not working.

I created a custom secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: keycloak-db-secret
data:
    POSTGRES_DATABASE: ...
    POSTGRES_EXTERNAL_ADDRESS: ...
    POSTGRES_EXTERNAL_PORT: ...
    POSTGRES_HOST: ...
    POSTGRES_USERNAME: ...
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ...
```

and keycloak with external db:

```
apiVersion: keycloak.org/v1alpha1
kind: Keycloak
metadata:
  labels:
      app: keycloak
  name: keycloak
spec:
  externalDatabase:
    enabled: true
  instances: 1
```

but when I check log, keycloak can not connect to db. It is still using default vaule: `keycloak-postgresql.keycloak` not value defined in my custom secret ? Why it is not using my value from secrets ?

**UPDATE**

when I check keycloak pod which was created by operator I can see:

```
  env:
    - name: DB_VENDOR
      value: POSTGRES
    - name: DB_SCHEMA
      value: public
    - name: DB_ADDR
      value: keycloak-postgresql.keycloak
    - name: DB_PORT
      value: '5432'
    - name: DB_DATABASE
      value: keycloak
    - name: DB_USER
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: keycloak-db-secret
          key: POSTGRES_USERNAME
    - name: DB_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: keycloak-db-secret
          key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
```

so now I know why I can not connect to db. It use different DB_ADDR. How I can use address: my-app.postgres (db in another namespace).

I dont know why POSTGRES_HOST in secret not working and pod still using default service name

Answer (score 2):

To connect with service in another namespace you can use.

```
<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

suppose your Postgres deployment and service running in **test** namespace it will go like

```
postgres.test.svc.cluster.local
```

this is what i am using : https://github.com/harsh4870/Keycloack-postgres-kubernetes-deployment/blob/main/keycload-deployment.yaml

i have also attached the Postgres file you can use it however in my case i have setup both in the **same** namespace **keycloak** and **Postgres** so working like charm.

Comment: sure this also work for me when I am creating keycloak without operator. But when keycloak is creating with operator it always create service with default value

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Azure PostgreSQL for that, and it works correctly. In pod configuration, it also uses `keycloak-postgresql.keycloak` as DB_ADDR, but this is pointing to my internal service created by operator based on `keycloak-db-secret`.

Answer (score 0):

keycloak-postgresql.keycloak this is the another service created by Keycloak Operator, which is used to connect to Postgresql's service.

You can check its endpoint.

```
$ kubectl get endpoints keycloak-postgresql -n keycloak
NAME                  ENDPOINTS           AGE
keycloak-postgresql   {postgresql's service ip}:5432   4m31s
```

However, the reason why it fails is due to the selector of this service:

```
selector:
  app: keycloak
  component: database
```

So if your DB Pod has the different Label, the selector will not work.
I reported this issue to the community. If they reply me, I will try to fix this bug by submitting a patch.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue, and then after looking at @JiyeYu 's answer, I have searched the project's issue backlog, and I've found some related issues that are still open (at the moment of this reply).

Particularly this one: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-18602

After reading this, and its comments, I did the following:

- Don't use IPs on POSTGRES_EXTERNAL_ADDRESS. If your PostGres is hosted within K8s via a StatefulSet, use the full `<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` (like @Harsh Manvar 's answer)
- Remove the POSTGRES_HOST setting from the secret (don't just set it to the default, delete it). Apparently, it is not only being ignored, but also breaking the keycloak pod initialization process somehow.

After I applied these changes the issue was solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problem, it turned out since I was using SSLMODE: "verify-full", keycloak expected correct hostname of my external db.

Since somehow Keycloak translates internally the real external db address into "keycloak-postgresql.keycloak", it expected something like "keycloak-postgresql.my-keycloak-namespace"

The log went something like this:

```
SEVERE [org.postgresql.ssl.PGjdbcHostnameVerifier] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) Server name validation failed: certificate for host keycloak-postgresql.my-keycloak-namespace dNSName entries subjectAltName, but none of them match. Assuming server name validation failed
```

After I added the host `keycloak-postgresql.my-keycloak-namespace` on the db certificate, it worked like advertised.